# Will adding the "Authenticated User" group to a folder within the wwwroot folder cause security holes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I added and gave the "Authenticated User" group modify/read/list/write permissions to one sub-folder inside the wwwroot folder. Will doing this cause a security hole?

[image]

Is so, what is a better alternative? Better still, is there a way I can give only the PHP.exe permission to write to this directory?

I did this to allow PHP (using Joom!a CMS) to be able to write to certain directories within that sub-directory. However, just giving the IIS_IUSRS or IUSR write and modify access did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As a baseline, giving anything Write access in a content folder is a potentially exploitable hole. If someone can write to that location, they can create (for example) unauthorized or unexpected code, or defacement, in that location.

PHP is a process that runs with a user identity; processes don't have an inherent identity on their own*, they act on behalf of the identity that starts them.

To answer the "better alternative" question: If your app needs it, you need it. But you're at the mercy of the app getting its security (and security of any internal published applications, scripts or tools) right.

*pedantry corner: Obviously, processes have a process token; the question implied it was possible to grant permissions directly to an EXE and not the user of that EXE, which isn't possible.

Comment: While this is not a clear answer, since this concerns security and the web, this may be as close to an answer we may get. The real problem, is that I'm not sure whom the PHP process runs as, I used to think it was the IUSR, but now in IIS 7, I do not think that this is always the case. Plus I've not seen any material on the net that clearly answers that either.